# XML Serialization With Properties inside Tags

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am currently working on an integration with an external company and the interactions are done using objects serialized into XML strings. The examples that I've been given and the responses from the external service include XML tags with properties inside the tags themselves.

i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response Version="3">
 <Status StatusCode="OK"></Status>
</Response>
```

Orignially I was expecting "OK" to be the value between the "Status" tags so that it would be deserialized as a string value on the resulting object but the "Status" field is ending up as an empty string, I'm assuming because the tag is technically empty.

I'm currently trying to use a `DataContractSerializer` due to it being the best fit given some other separate requirements but I am unsure how to handle tags like the "Status" example.

Is a `DataContractSerializer` capable of deserializing the "Status" tag in its current form? If not, what type of serializer should be used to accomodate this scenario?

Also, any resources or help with search terms for what this  XML structure is called would be appreciated.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858798/datacontract-xml-serialization-and-xml-attributes

Comment: Those are Attributes, not Elements

Comment: @djv ahh that explains the lack of progress googling. Thanks for clarifying that. Unfortunately it looks like DataContractSerializer doesn't support attributes. So...back to the drawing board.

Comment: DataContractSerializer does support `IXmlSerializable` though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861220/3744182) for an example, so for **very simple** objects (i.e. just an attribute) that would be an option.  But for more complex objects with child elements, implementing `IXmlSerializable` is brutal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize to these classes

```vb
Public Class Response
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement()>
    Public Property Status As Status
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()>
    Public Property Version As Integer
End Class

Public Class Status
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()>
    Public Property StatusCode As String
End Class
```

(`Version` and `StatusCode` are Attributes)

Here is the serialization

```vb
Dim s As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(Response))
Dim r As Response

' reading
Using fs As New IO.FileStream("filename.xml", IO.FileMode.Open)
    r = s.Deserialize(fs)
End Using

' writing
Using fs As New IO.FileStream("filename.xml", IO.FileMode.Truncate)
    s.Serialize(fs, r)
End Using
```

If it helps, the xml could also be represented like this, which should make it clear why the `Status` element itself has no string value.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response Version="3">
  <Status StatusCode="OK"/>
</Response>
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to accomplish this using a `DataContractSerializer` because of some other requiements that have nothing to do with this question. Unfortunately it looks like `DataContractSerializer` doesn't support attributes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I've never used `DataContractSerializer` but **doesn't support attributes** doesn't seem right.

Comment: I've seen it stated in two places, [1, Accepted answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/867d9872-3206-46d9-a22b-2ab59f251f99/adding-an-xml-attribute-to-a-datacontract?forum=wcf), [2, The accepted answer here does show how but its not supported out of the box.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4859260/914779)