# Easiest way to serialize an IParsable<T> as a string using the DataContract model?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontractserializer, .net-7.0

I want to serialize `IParsable<MyType>` as `<mns:MyType>MyType.ToString()</mns:MyType>` in the context of a broader serialization requiring the `DataContract` serialization approach (`readonly` fields, etc.).

I have tried several ways, including `ISerializable` and `ISerializationSurrogate`, but they have all led to a lot of code that looks confusingly different to the `DataContract` attributes used throughout, and leaves me sure I'm using the wrong tools.  It should be easy - `MyType` casts to and from `string`.  What's the easiest way?

Comment: What is wrong with following example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for implementing a data contract serialization surrogate **in .NET Core** for some type `MyType` are as follows:

1. Create a surrogate type that can be serialized via the data contract serializer, and can be converted back and forth from the original type `MyType`.
2. create a surrogate provider type [`ISerializationSurrogateProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider) that implements the following methods:

   - [`GetSurrogateType(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider.getsurrogatetype) - returns the surrogate type when passed `typeof(MyType)`.
   - [`GetObjectToSerialize(Object, Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider.getobjecttoserialize) - returns an instance of the surrogate when passed an instance of `MyType`.
   - [`GetDeserializedObject(Object, Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogateprovider.getdeserializedobject) - returns an instance of `MyType` when passed the surrogate.
3. Before serializing or deserializing, construct your own `DataContractSerializer` and call [`DataContractSerializerExtensions.SetSerializationSurrogateProvider(provider)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializerextensions.setserializationsurrogateprovider) to register an instance of the provider from step #2 with the serializer.

**Important notes**

- The method for using data contract surrogates in .NET Framework is **completely different** from .NET Core.  If you are working in .NET Framework, ignore this answer and see [Data Contract Surrogates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates).
- In your `ToString()` method, be sure to format all numeric and other values using **[`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture)**.  If you don't, XML generated in one locale will be unreadable in another.  If you need a localized `ToString()` for some reason, make `MyType` implement [`IFormattable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable) and use [`ToString(default, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable.tostring) when serializing.  (The `format` string can be ignored.)
- You mentioned attempting to use `ISerializable` for your `MyType`.  This technique stores data as element/value pairs in the XML serialization stream.  Since your desired XML contains only text and no markup elements, this approach is probably not appropriate.

With that in mind, we can create a generic surrogate for any type implementing `IParsable<TSelf>` as follows:

```
public sealed class ParsableSurrogate<TSelf> where TSelf : IParsable<TSelf>
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public TSelf? Value { get; set; }

    public string? TextValue { get { return Value?.ToString(); } set { Value = (value == null ? default : TSelf.Parse(value, default)); } }
}
```

Next, make the following `ISerializationSurrogateProvider`:

```
public class SerializationSurrogateProvider : ISerializationSurrogateProvider
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, (Type SurrogateType, Func<object, Type, object> ToSurrogate)> toSurrogateDictionary = new();
    readonly Dictionary<Type, (Type OriginalType, Func<object, Type, object> ToOriginal)> fromSurrogateDictionary = new();
    
    public Type GetSurrogateType(Type type) =>
        toSurrogateDictionary.TryGetValue(type, out var entry) ? entry.SurrogateType : type;

    // TODO: check to see whether null objects are handled correctly

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType) =>
        toSurrogateDictionary.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out var entry) ? entry.ToSurrogate(obj, targetType) : obj;

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType) =>
        fromSurrogateDictionary.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out var entry) ? entry.ToOriginal(obj, targetType) : obj;
        
    public SerializationSurrogateProvider AddParsable<TParsable>() where TParsable : IParsable<TParsable>
    {
        toSurrogateDictionary.Add(typeof(TParsable), (typeof(ParsableSurrogate<TParsable>), (obj, t) => new ParsableSurrogate<TParsable> { Value = (TParsable)obj }));
        fromSurrogateDictionary.Add(typeof(ParsableSurrogate<TParsable>), (typeof(TParsable), (obj, t) => ((ParsableSurrogate<TParsable>)obj).Value!));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say your `MyType` looks like this:

```
public class MyType : IParsable<MyType>
{
    public MyType(string? value1, string? value2) => (this.Value1, this.Value2) = (value1, value2);
    
    public string? Value1 { get; }
    public string? Value2 { get; }
    
    public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
    
    public static MyType Parse (string s, IFormatProvider? provider) => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyType>(s) ?? throw new ArgumentException();
    public static bool TryParse (string? s, IFormatProvider? provider, out MyType result) => throw new NotImplementedException("not needed for the question");
}
```

Then to serialize from and to XML, you create a `DataContractSerializer` as follows for any model type that contains an instance of `MyType` as follows:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(model.GetType());
serializer.SetSerializationSurrogateProvider(new SerializationSurrogateProvider().AddParsable<MyType>());

var xml = model.ToContractXml(serializer : serializer);

var model2 = DataContractSerializerHelper.FromContractXml<Model>(xml, serializer);
```

Using the extension methods:

```
public static partial class DataContractSerializerHelper
{
    public static string ToContractXml<T>(this T obj, DataContractSerializer? serializer = null, XmlWriterSettings? settings = null)
    {
        serializer = serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(obj == null ? typeof(T) : obj.GetType());
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            settings = settings ?? new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T? FromContractXml<T>(string xml, DataContractSerializer? serializer = null)
    {
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml ?? ""))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            return (T?)(serializer ?? new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T))).ReadObject(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

When `MyType` is the root model itself, the XML generated will look like the following:

```xml
<ParsableSurrogateOfMyTypeMTRdQN6P xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
  <TextValue>{"Value1":"hello","Value2":"there"}</TextValue>
</ParsableSurrogateOfMyTypeMTRdQN6P>
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KMDXWV).

While this works, you will notice a couple problems:

1. The text value is nested inside a `<TextValue>` element.  In your question, you made it clear you don't want that.

   Since `DataContractSerializer` does not support an equivalent to the `[XmlText]` attribute of `XmlSerializer`, it will be necessary to implement `IXmlSerializable`.
2. The root element name, `<ParsableSurrogateOfMyTypeMTRdQN6P>`, is stupid, and doesn't match your requirement, which is `<mns:MyType>`.

   Since we will be implementing `IXmlSerializable`, it will be necessary to use the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47861221/3744182) to *[How can I control the root element namespace and name when serializing an IXmlSerializable object with the data contract serializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47861220/3744182)*.

This requires modifying `ParsableSurrogate<TSelf>` as follows:

```
[XmlSchemaProvider("GetSchemaMethod")]
public sealed class ParsableSurrogate<TSelf> : IXmlSerializable where TSelf : IParsable<TSelf>
{
    public TSelf? Value { get; set; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        Value = TSelf.Parse(reader.ReadElementContentAsString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) => writer.WriteValue(Value?.ToString());
    public XmlSchema? GetSchema() => null;
    
    const string DataContractNamespacePrefix = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/";

    static void GetDataContractNamespaceAndName(Type type, out string name, out string @namespace)
    {
        // TODO: tweak this logic as required to get the correct namespace and name
        (name, @namespace) = (type.Name, DataContractNamespacePrefix + type.Namespace);
        if (type.GetCustomAttribute<DataContractAttribute>() is {} attr)
            (name, @namespace) = (attr.Name ?? name, attr.Namespace ?? @namespace);
    }
    
    // This is the method named by the XmlSchemaProviderAttribute applied to the type.
    public static XmlQualifiedName GetSchemaMethod(XmlSchemaSet xs)
    {
        GetDataContractNamespaceAndName(typeof(TSelf), out var name, out var @namespace);
        // Create the TSelf type as a restriction of string
        var tSelfType = new XmlSchemaSimpleType
        {
            Name = name,
            Content = new XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction { BaseTypeName = XmlSchemaType.GetBuiltInSimpleType(XmlTypeCode.String).QualifiedName },
        };
        // Create the top-level TSelf element.
        var tSelfElement = new XmlSchemaElement
        {
            Name = name,
            SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName(tSelfType.Name, @namespace),
        };
        // Create a schema with the type & element
        var tSelfSchema = new XmlSchema
        {
            TargetNamespace = @namespace,
            // Add the top-level element and types to the schema
            Items = { tSelfElement, tSelfType },
        };
        xs.Add(tSelfSchema);
        return new XmlQualifiedName(name, @namespace);
    }
}
```

And adding the required data contract namespace to `MyType` like so:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912029")] // Replace with whatever namespace you need
public class MyType : IParsable<MyType>
{
```

Having done this, the following XML will be generated for `MyType`:

```xml
<MyType xmlns="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912029">{"Value1":"hello","Value2":"there"}</MyType>
```

And for a model that contains a list of `MyType` such as the following:

```
public class Model
{
    public List<MyType?> MyTypes { get; set; } = new ();
}
```

The following XML is generated, as required:

```xml
<Model xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/">
  <MyTypes xmlns:d2p1="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75912029">
    <d2p1:MyType>{"Value1":"hello","Value2":"there"}</d2p1:MyType>
    <d2p1:MyType i:nil="true" />
    <d2p1:MyType>{"Value1":"foo","Value2":"bar"}</d2p1:MyType>
  </MyTypes>
</Model>
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HUlVwl).

Comment: Thanks.  A lot to work through, but you have covered all angles.  Was hoping I'd missed something a lot easier - I assumed going with IParsable would simplify serialisation...  Still, at least (in my case) the simple XML element will be more intuitive to edit, so it will still be worth it.